# Would a frame of 44mm x 18mm wood be strong enough to support MDF doors?

Tags: wood-selection

I'm designing my first indoor bit of furniture and I'm planning to hide some Ikea bookshelves behind some MDF doors to make some built in cupboards

I was going to use the following 18x44mm timber for the framing but I'm hearing concerns about it "not being thick enough", and my separate (and much more reasonable) own concerns about it splitting when I screw the front plate MDF into it

I'd use thicker wood but the space between the bookcases and the walls on each side is 40mm so I'm pretty limited

Any advice would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  I assume you are putting the framing in to hang the doors from, so can you give us some information about the doors including material, dimensions, hinge types, & etc.  Also clarify what you mean by "front plate".

Comment: 18x44mm isn't unsubstantial and could well be strong enough for your needs but it depends on some of the things you haven't told us yet. To start with just saying "timber" tells us nothing except that you plan to use wood :-) Huuuge difference between spruce and, say, oak. Not that a softwood is automatically too weak for this, depending on a few factors including the type of hinge you plan to use and how many of them will be required to take the weight of the doors. Speaking of the doors, you should do some quick back-of-envelope sums to see what weight they'll be so you can work accordingly.

Comment: *"own concerns about it splitting when I screw the front plate MDF into it"* Wood shouldn't split when screwed into if you drill properly sized pilot holes first. Like @Ashlar I don't know what you mean by "front plate".

Comment: I suspect if you used a piano hinge, you'd have no problems, but of course more info would be better.

Comment: @bowlturner, I was going to say piano hinge might be ruled out based on the 18mm thickness but TIL it's available in a wide range of sizes. It is known to be hard to install neatly though, and, um, well, they are *complete* overkill for simple panel doors :-D

Comment: @Graphus  I've used piano hinges on 3/4" boards, my idea was that you get many small screws each one less likely to put too much stress on the board.   could even use a couple smaller/shorter ones, though that would make it more difficult to align them well.